# Procurar/selecionar banco de dados com C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, winforms, datagridview, microsoft-access

Eu tenho um form com um botão e um datagridView simples, mas o meu problema é que eu tenho que procurar o meu arquivo em ".mdb" (banco de dados do Access) no computador, para aí sim ser mostrado no datagridView então fica a pergunta:

Ao clicar no botão, quero que apareça um openFileDialog, onde o usuário procura o banco de dados, então quando ele selecionar o arquivo já popule o datagridView com as informações do banco que ele selecionou.

Há algum jeito de fazer isso?

tentei usar um modelo que o derpirscher (usuário do Stack overflow dos EUA) me aconselhou, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
  dlg.Filter = "Database Files|*.mdb";
  if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
  string dbfile = dlg.FileName;
  string connectstring = string.format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}";Persist Security Info=False;, dbfile);

 using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectstring)) {
     //..realiza as query's
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Poste o que você já tentou fazer.

Comment: O código esta praticamente pronto, basta você incluir a query de consulta no local indicado, algum erro encontrado?

Comment: Para popular sua grid com os dados você vai ter que criar um método para leitura do arquivo.

Comment: o que eu estou em dúvida é como que vou acionar no click do "open" para chamar o arquivo as conexões com o oledb, como posso transformar 
`@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                           "Data Source=C:\myPath\myFile.mdb;" +                                    
                           "Persist Security Info=True;" +
                           "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=myPassword;"` em algo dinâmico, já que o banco de dados deve ser procurado no pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt, sua connectionstring já está dinâmica, ela pega o caminho do banco de dados através da variável dbfile (que recebe dlg.FileName). A partir daí, sempre que precisar da connectionstring utilize sua variável.

Comment: ajudou muito (por falta de atenção não percebi que realmente tava separado) ! desmontei todos os itens da string (delimitando por "\\") e funcionou, agora tenho que fazer a conexão ir corretamente, teria alguma ideia?

Comment: Quando você monta a string com o string.Format, está fechando a string antes do "Persist Security Info", ele faz parte da connectionstring. Experimente string connectstring = string.format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=False;", dbfile); (trocando as aspas de lugar).